# Opposite of "numerous"

Tags: antonyms

What is the opposite of *numerous*? I expected the answer to be *innumerous*, but that seems to mean *too many to count*. There must be a negative to *numerous* that isn't simply *few*.

Comment: Is there something wrong with *not many*?  If so, please clarify; if not, this is general reference.

Comment: *not many* doesn't have the same force as *numerous* in the opposite direction. There may not be a strong enough antonym, though.

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/few

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many contexts, one antonym is **scarce** or [scant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scant) *(2b : lacking in amplitude or quantity)*

Answer (score 1):

In the singular, you could use '*modicum*' or '*trifle*'/'*trifling amount*'.

Answer (score 1):

In grammatical terminology, the word *paucal* is commonly used, but it's not common in other situations.